# (Linux) How to get filename/path by function name

Tags: bash, find, traceback

I have strange "autocomplete" in bash "_shells" i never had before.

Before i never saw it.
And now if i type "_she" and press tab in makes "autocomplete" > _shells

By executing "$type -a _shells" it prints out

```
type -a  _shells 
_shells is a function
_shells () 
{ 
    local shell rest;
    while read -r shell rest; do
        [[ $shell == /* && $shell == "$cur"* ]] && COMPREPLY+=($shell);
    done 2> /dev/null < /etc/shells
}
```

if i execute $_shells, nothing displays at all.
I cant trace location of filename which contains this function.

realpath _shells > no output
readlink _shells > no output
etc ...

How can i get filename of this unknown function ?

Thanks!

PS: i should post it on SuperUser i guess ? Sorry about that!

Comment: `man -k _shells` led me to `man pam_shells` .. might help

Comment: yes; but its not same i think, i may case _shells is something like alias.

Comment: Have a look in /etc/profile and /etc/.bash_rc. It cannot be in many more places...

Comment: No, its not in there.